# Remove single quote VBA function

Tags: vba, excel, quote

To simplify, I have two sheets in an Excel workbook.

If I write `=sheet2!R3C2` in one of the cells of sheet1, the cell takes the value of the cell R3C2 of sheet2 correctly. 
I would like to generalize that for many rows in VBA, so my code is:

```
row = XX a long 

temp = "=sheet2!R" & row - 1 & "C2"

Range("c" & row).Value = temp
```

But when I use this code, the value of the cell(row,3) is       `=sheet2!'RXXC2'`

How can I remove the single quotes ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Range("C" & row).Formula = temp
```

would produce the correct formula in your cell.

What you should consider doing instead of looping is

```
Range("A1").Formula = "=Sheet2!$B1"
Range("A1").Resize(100, 1).Formula = Range("A1").Formula
```

The first line inserts a formula `=Sheet2!$B1` in cell A1 of your active sheet. The `$` *dollar sign* assures that the column will not be incremented (*same applies with numbers*)

Then the second line duplicates the formula across 100 rows down from A1 replacing the number after the `B` *column*

So now

```
A1 =Sheet2!B1
A2 =Sheet2!B2
A3 =Sheet2!B3
...
```

Also, it's a bit unclear what you're trying to actually do so consider another option which is saving the value of formula into another range using the `Evaluate()` function

`Range("c" & row).Value = Evaluate(temp)` Or `Range("C" & Row).Value = [temp]`

Comment: It looks like there is a transpose going on though… the variable "row" is addressing a "column" in the `Range("c" & row)` part. Also, since OP appears to be using R1C1 addressing you need FormulaR1C1 I think.

Comment: @Floris sorry but I dont understand why you think there is a transpose going on? I think the OP is just trying to reference relative cells from other sheet.

Comment: Ah… I was in R1C1 mode and saw `C…`. Sorry. I actually had originally written a solution like yours, but using `R[-1]C3` to indicate how to do "one row up, column 3" in R1C1 - but never saved the edit since I thought it was not what he was doing. I need more sleep.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the formula, not the value:

```
Range("c"&row).FormulaR1C1 = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

try to write `Range("c" & row).FormulaR1C1=temp`